# convergence prove of $a(n) = \frac{n}{4^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

i need to prove that the following sequence converges:

$$a(n) = \frac{n}{4^n}$$

in the assignment there is also a hint:
prove that $2^n \gt n $ holds true for every $n \ge  0 $

i can prove that with the bernoulli inequality [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)

$$(1+x)^n \gt 1+ nx $$

what i did was to plug in the inequality from the hint:

$$1+2n \lt (1+2)^2$$

now i simply distributed the power of 2 into the right term, after that i substracted 1 from the whole inequation:

$$2 \le 2n \lt 2^2 $$

not quite sure how this hint is going to help me, the denominator of $a(n) = \frac{n}{4^n}$ however is an geometric sequence and as such has an infinite limit because $q = 4 \gt 0$, the nominator on the other hand is also infinite but less then the denominator, naively the sequence converges against 0 but i cannot prove this claim!

Comment: What does "distributed the power of $2$" mean?  I hope you are not saying that $(1+2)^2=1^2+2^2$.

Comment: well this is embarassing, i did actualy ...

Comment: Do you actually think that $2\leqslant2n\lt2^2$ for every $n$?

Comment: You really need to make sure you are totally on top of basic algebra before you attempt more advanced topics.  Hope this comment doesn't come across as offensive, I'm just trying to be helpful.

Comment: no it does not, but im kinda forced to learn basic algebra and advanced stuff at the same time...

Comment: That's unfortunate.  You will need to organise your study carefully and I would recommend putting the majority of your time into the basics.  Perhaps just do enough on the advanced things to keep in touch.  Then as you get more on top of the basics, decrease the time on them and give more time to advanced work.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use induction to show that $n<2^n$. When $n=1$, the result is trivial. Now, assume that $2^n>n$ is true.
Then,
$$2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^n>2n=n+n>n+1\mbox{, as we are assuming $n\geq1$ (we've proved it for $n=1$).}$$
So,
$$2^{n+1}>n+1$$
Thus, letting $m=n+1$ shows that the inequality is true for $m>1$.

You need to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a(n)\to x, \mbox{$x$ is some finite number}$$
So, use the hint:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n}{4^n}<\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2^n}{4^n}=\dfrac{1}{2^n}\to0$$
So,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a(n)\to0\mbox{ therefore, it converges.}$$

Answer (score 2):

To use the hint, use it on the numerator:

$$\dfrac{n}{4^n} < \dfrac{2^n}{4^n} = \left(\dfrac{2}{4}\right)^n = \dfrac{1}{2^n} \to 0$$

You can also prove $n < 2^n$ with induction.

Answer (score 0):

> $$a>1\Rightarrow\frac n{a^n}\to 0$$

Let us prove that there is a $C$ such as, for each $b>1$:

$$
\frac n{b^n}\leq C
$$

- if it is true for $n$, then 
  $$
  \frac {n+1}{b^{n+1}} = \frac {n+1}{bn}\frac n{b^n} \leq C\frac {n+1}{bn}\leq C
  $$
  as soon as $(b-1)n\ge 1$.
- Now take $$
  C = \max \{n{2^n}|(b-1)n\ge 1\}
  $$
  We have $$
  \frac n{2^n}\leq C
  $$as soon as $(b-1)n\ge 1$
  and for bigger values of $n$ it is true because of induction.

Now, 
$$
\frac n{a^n} = \frac n{b^n}\left[\frac ab\right]^n \leq C \left[\frac ab\right]^n \to 0
$$
as soon as $1<b<a$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the fact that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{4^n}$ converges by the ratio test.

For $n>0$

$$\frac{n+1}{4^{n+1}}\frac{4^n}{n}=\frac{1}{4}\bigg(1+\frac{1}n{}\bigg)\to \frac{1}{4}<1$$.

Hence $\frac{n}{4^n} \to 0$

Answer (score 0):

Here it is another formal proof,

Given  $\epsilon>0$ there exists $A(\epsilon)> \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ such that for $a\geq A(\epsilon)$ we have;

$\displaystyle{|a_{(n)}-0|=\frac{a}{4^a}< \frac{2^a}{4^a}= \frac{1}{2^a} < \frac{1}{a}<\frac{1}{A(\epsilon)}< \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}}= \epsilon$

Which concludes the proof.